# Using database without any installation

Tags: java, database

I'm working on a program and I was wondering how to proceed since I don't want the person 
that is going to use it to install any driver or make the odbc step to make the database 
functional.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use HSQLDB, you just need to include the jar in your classpath and you are good to go. 
[HSQLDB documentation](http://hsqldb.org/)

Comment: HSQLDB is a light weight pure implementation of a SQL DB.  Goes anywhere

Answer (score 0):

SQLite saves the database in a compact file format. It's just a library for your program that accesses the database in the file, and requires no setup or installation.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll look forward to it and to HSQLDB too.